# Drawing a form when a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript

I have a form with some options on it. I want to draw a new form depending on which was clicked.
I'm new to Javascript so I know I'm doing this wrong but I can't seem to find the correct way to do this.
Here's my code.

```
<form>
        <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "facebook" value="Facebook" checked="checked"/>Facebook
        <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "twitter" value="Twitter"/>Twitter
        <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "tumblr" value="Tumblr"/>Tumblr
        <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "instagram" value="Instagram"/>Instagram
    </form>
    <script>
    if (content.getElementById('facebook').checked)
    {

    }
    else if (content.getElementById('twitter').checked)
    {

    }
    else if (content.getElementById('tumblr').checked)
    {
        <form name="newPostTumblr" action="" method="">
        <h2>Tumblr</h2>
        <p><label for="postTitle">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="postTitle" /></p>
        <p><label for="postContent">Content:</label> <input type="text" id="postContent" /></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Hey Travis, instead of trying to post an answer, I'll just make some suggestions on how to re-think the problem you're trying to solve that I'm sort of seeing answered in the answers section.  First, think of HTML as the skeleton of the site which Javascript operates on.  It exists independent of Javascript and its code.  Thus, you can print your forms in the HTML and use Javascript to show and hide the forms by their Id.  To "hide" an object, consider setting the "display" property, a la [display property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

Comment: But note: http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax it must be doucment instead of content..

**Replace**

```
if (content.getElementById('facebook').checked)
```

**with**

```
if (document.getElementById('facebook').checked)
----^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: There is a far greater misunderstanding of Javascript and its relationship with HTML than simply where from the DOM the forms need to be accessed.

Comment: Thanks, although not everything I needed.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I need a way of showing a form when a radio button is checked. I would like to avoid jQuery.

Comment: @TravisMcKee well i am in rush thats why i gave you example code....all you need to do is just replace alert with form...with `document.write('<form>facebook</form>')` for facebook radio selection and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution avoiding jQuery that hides your forms as necessary.  Working jsFiddle for your reference: http://jsfiddle.net/vwnP6/1/:

HTML of forms:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "facebook" value="Facebook" checked="checked"/>Facebook
    <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "twitter" value="Twitter"/>Twitter
    <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "tumblr" value="Tumblr"/>Tumblr
    <input type="radio" name="postTo" id = "instagram" value="Instagram"/>Instagram
</form>
<form id="facebookForm" action="" method="">
    <h2>Facebook</h2>
    <p><label for="postTitle">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="postTitle" /></p>
    <p><label for="postContent">Content:</label> <input type="text" id="postContent" /></p>
</form>
<form id="twitterForm" action="" method="">
    <h2>Twitter</h2>
    <p><label for="postTitle">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="postTitle" /></p>
    <p><label for="postContent">Content:</label> <input type="text" id="postContent" /></p>
</form>
<form id="tumblrForm" action="" method="">
    <h2>Tumblr</h2>
    <p><label for="postTitle">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="postTitle" /></p>
    <p><label for="postContent">Content:</label> <input type="text" id="postContent" /></p>
</form>
<form id="instagramForm" action="" method="">
    <h2>Instagram</h2>
    <p><label for="postTitle">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="postTitle" /></p>
    <p><label for="postContent">Content:</label> <input type="text" id="postContent" /></p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
// Our various radio buttons
// We can define these globally since that's how Javascript works
// Would be better to have this all encapsulated into its own "class" to keep namespace clean
var facebook_radio = document.getElementById('facebook');
var twitter_radio = document.getElementById('twitter');
var tumblr_radio = document.getElementById('tumblr');
var instagram_radio = document.getElementById('instagram');

function hideElement(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function showElement(element) {
    element.style.display = "block";
    element.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function changeForm() {
    /* Hide all forms and show desired form based on checked radio button */

    // Our form elements
    var facebook_form = document.getElementById("facebookForm");
    var twitter_form = document.getElementById("twitterForm");
    var tumblr_form = document.getElementById("tumblrForm");
    var instagram_form = document.getElementById("instagramForm");

    // Hide all of our forms
    hideElement(facebook_form);
    hideElement(twitter_form);
    hideElement(tumblr_form);
    hideElement(instagram_form);

    // Show appropriate form
    if (facebook_radio.checked)
    {
        showElement(facebook_form);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('twitter').checked)
    {
        showElement(twitter_form);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('tumblr').checked)
    {
        showElement(tumblr_form);
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('instagram').checked)
    {
        showElement(instagram_form);   
    }
}
// When you select a radio button, you want to change to correct form
facebook_radio.onchange = changeForm;
twitter_radio.onchange = changeForm;
tumblr_radio.onchange = changeForm;
instagram_radio.onchange = changeForm;
// Show first checked form
changeForm();
```

Comment: Seems to work on JSFiddle. But I can't get it to work in code. It shows all of them down the webpage.

Comment: An exact copy-paste of your code, and nothing. Would really be nice if I could get a response back with help regarding why it might not be showing. I did reference the stylesheet.

Comment: Hey Travis, The Javascript must execute after the HTML has been rendered.  Try these two things: 1) Put the code in a `<script type="text/javascript>` set of tags in the `<head>` portion of your website. And put `onload="changeForm();"` into your `<body>` tag.  This will execute `changeForm()` after the body finishes loading.  2) Put the `<script>` and code after the HTML.

Answer (score -3):

With jQuery:

```
if ($("#facebook").attr("checked") == true) { // checks if the attribute "checked" is true
    $("#form").show(); // displays the element: http://api.jquery.com/show/
} else {
    $("#form").hide(); // hides the element. http://api.jquery.com/hide/
}
```

The code above should be executed on a click event detected. You can use it in code like this:

```
$("#facebook").click(function() {
    // execute code here
});
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar but jQuery is JavaScript and it is not specified if jQuery cannot be used. His original solution does not have jQuery used, thus jQuery was not tagged.

Comment: but if OP were open for jQuery then he must have added it...right.?

Comment: @DipeshParmar I'm not sure if he is aware of jQuery, since he mentioned that he was a newbie.

Comment: Is there a non jQuery example? Where would I put my form? How would I hide it?

Comment: @TravisMcKee you would put your form in a class with the id "form". If you want to hide it initially, use the `.hide()` function. jQuery is not required for this, but it makes life easier.

Comment: @wei2912 Would that be inside the script tag? or outside?

Comment: @TravisMcKee all inside, you just need to include the jQuery file. Please read http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: I would like to try to avoid jQuery at the moment. Another thing I dont want to have to learn right now. Is there a way of doing this without jQuery but still be somewhat simple?